# Angular form: How to ensure at least one item of a multi-choice button group is selected

Tags: angular, validation

I have an angular form with the following button group
[screenshot of buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXZDU.png)

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle d-block" formGroupName="usages">
        <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn" [class.btn-secondary]="usages.leisureUse">
          <input ngbButton type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="usages.leisureUse" formControlName="leisureUse"> Leisure Use
        </label>
        <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn" [class.btn-secondary]="usages.commuteUse">
          <input ngbButton type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="usages.commuteUse" formControlName="commuteUse"> Commute Use
        </label>
        <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn" [class.btn-secondary]="usages.competitionUse">
          <input ngbButton type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="usages.competitionUse" formControlName="competitionUse"> Competition Use
        </label>
      </div>
```

and in the component:

```
searchForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      usages: this.formBuilder.group({
        leisureUse: ["", [Validators.required]],
        commuteUse: ["", [Validators.required]],
        competitionUse: ["", [Validators.required]]
      }, { updateOn: "change" }
    // ...
}
// ---

// model storing state
  usages = {
    leisureUse: false,
    commuteUse: false,
    competitionUse: false
  };
```

I need to validate that at least one of these checkbox buttons is selected however I can't seem to figure out how. I've looked into creating a custom validator although it was never triggered, now do I know what code to put in the validator.

Comment: NOT use `[(ngModel)]` -you're using Reactive Forms-, the custom error make over the formGroup `usages` it's only check if one value is true

Answer (score 0):

you can make a formgroup Validation for validating like

```
const heroForm = new FormGroup({
  'name': new FormControl(),
  'alterEgo': new FormControl(),
  'power': new FormControl()
}, { validators: identityRevealedValidator });
```

src: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#adding-cross-validation-to-reactive-forms